# "Invalid block tag on line 3: 'providers_media_js', Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Tags: html, django, django-allauth, social-authentication

["Invalid block tag on line 3: 'providers_media_js', Did you forget to register or load this tag?"  why this is happening. What modification should I do to solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HFY0.png)

```
{% load static %}
{% load socialaccount % }
{% providers_media_js %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Creative Colorlib SignUp Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="{% static 'login.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- //Custom Theme files -->
<!-- web font -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- //web font -->
</head>
<body>

<div class="login-page">

  <div class="form" text-align="center">
  {% for message in messages %}
  <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
    <form class="login-form" action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="id" required="" />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required="" />
      <button action="" type='submit'>Login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Create an account</a></p>
      <p> or sign in with</p>
      <button> <a style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;" href="{% provider_login_url "google" %}">Google Login </a></button>
      <button> <a style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;" href="#">Facebook Login </a></button>
    </form>

  </div>
  <script src="{% static 'login.js'%}"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

help me find the solution

Comment: load is missing in {% providers_media_js %}, It should be {% load providers_media_js %}

Answer (score 0):

Change the beginning of your template from that :

```
{% load static %}
{% load socialaccount % }
{% providers_media_js %}
```

with

```
{% load static %}
{% load socialaccount % }
{% load providers_media_js %}
```

or

```
{% load static %}
{% load socialaccount providers_media_js % }
```

the **load** keyword is required to loads a custom template tag set

[Template tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#load)

Comment: But still there is an error on <button> <a style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;" href="{% provider_login_url "google" %}">Google Login </a></button>
      <button> <a style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;" href="#">Facebook Login </a></button>

Comment: Edit your question with traceback